# Div with position absolute having innerwidth of div with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

The last two days I've been reading most questions here and a lot more about '*fill remaining width*' and '*escaping overflow: hidden*', but I can't get my problem solved. At the moment, I seriously doubt if it is possible at all.

I have a scrolling box with full body width. On top of that I have a absolute positioned header that I need to make the exact same width as the scrollbox. My intention is to make the header `0px` or (if needed) `1px` in height and let the content overflow.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz8cydmo/4/).

The scrollbox has a scrollbar (always visible), the header obviously not. To compensate for that, I float a fake scrollbar to the right inside the header container, and left of that a `<div>` filling the remaining width (being exactly the innerwidth of the scrollbox).

**HTML**

```
//THE SCROLLBOX
<div id="scrollbox">
  <div id="center2">
    content<br>content<br>...
  </div>
</div>


// THE HEADER 
<div id="header_box">
  <!--- FAKE SCROLLBAR -->
  <div id="scroller">
    <div></div>
  </div>

  // REMAINING WIDTH
  <div id="container">

    <div id="FIRST">
      <div id="FIRST_banner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="SECOND">
    <div id="SECOND_banner"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header_box {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

#scroller {
  float: right;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
}

#scroller>div {
  width: 0px;
  height: 101%;
}

#container {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#FIRST {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 25px;
  background: pink;
}

#FIRST_banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 220px;
  width: 30px;
  background: crimson;
}

#SECOND {
  background: darkcyan;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
}

#SECOND_banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 220px;
  width: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
```

The problem lies in the div (`#FIRST`) with **remaining width**. From all the solutions I've read only the one with

```
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
```

works for me. It gives the exact width, lining up the center of the header and the scrollbox nicely. But I can't break out of the `overflow: hidden`, so it cuts off the content.

So my second thought was: wrap `#FIRST` in a `#container` and let the child determine the width of the parent. After that, I can put another div (`#SECOND`) inside the container with the width of the parent. It works partially. The `#container` has the width intended, and the `#SECOND` div overflows nicely but takes on the width of `#header_box`, as no width is set on the parent itself.

So, my questions:

1. Can I somehow break out of the `overflow: hidden` of the FIRST div? (In that case the container and second div can be removed).
2. Is there a way to let the SECOND div obey the width of it's parent.
3. Some totally different solution.

Sadly there is a catch to this all:

- css only
- no javascript
- no flexbox

Thanks voor any toughts.

Comment: Sorry the layout makes no sense to me, what are the purposes of the red and blue vertical bars?

Comment: They are both supposed to overflow from the container. The red is clipped, the purple is overflowing but not in the right position.

Comment: I think I have an idea what you want...please review this: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/hqg4h16f/1/

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear enough. The orange box starts at  50% of the scrollbox width. I only need one of the red or blue boxes to work, and the goal is to align the left hand side of red/blue exactly with the left hand side of the orange box, Pink and lightblue are the header containers. As you see pink has the right width but clips the content, lightblue doesn't clip but it is to wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was the good old `<table>` that saved the day, much simpler than I tought. There still is a fake scrollbar, but the absolute header now aligns perfect with the contents of the scrollable `div` behind it, and it remains fluid.

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wjuz4avj/2/)

**HTML:**

```
  <!--- HEADER  -->
  <div id="THIRD">
    <div id="THIRD_A">
      <div id="THIRD_B"></div>
      <div id="THIRD_C"></div>
      <div id="THIRD_D"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--- FAKE SCROLLBAR -->
  <div id="scroller">
    <div></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* The container for the header */
#header_box{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  display: table;
}

/* Takes on the width of its child: the fake scrollbar */
#scroller {
  display: table-cell;
  float: right;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
/* This triggers a scrollbar to be shown */
#scroller>div {
  width: 0px;
  height: 101%;
}



/* The 'remaining width' container (= screenwidth - scrollbar, equals innerwidth of scrollbox) */
#THIRD{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    }
/* Needed to give the children a 'width' reference */
#THIRD_A{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    }

/* The actual header items */   
#THIRD_B {
position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 220px;
  background: black;
}
#THIRD_C {
position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  width: 125px;
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
}
#THIRD_D {
position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 220px;
  background: black;
}
```

**NOTE:**
On most handheld browser, this is 1px off. It seems webkit based browsers display a tablecell of 0px width as 1px width [(see this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331082/chrome-displaying-table-cell-with-0-width-as-1px). The solution is to wrap the table in another div with css:

```
position absolute;
left: 0;
right: -1px
```

and setting `#scroller>div` to a width of `1px`.

**NOTE 2:**
This is also a solution for a fixed div inside a scrollable div. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93v6au4w/1/)